# Measure complaining column doesn't existing when it does

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to do a new mesaure but for some reason its not recnoising my column name even though I renamed it to price instead of unit_price

[image]

You will see there is a price and a quantity I am wanting to do a new mesaure on the multiply of those items of those so I tried.

But when I tried it it didnt like it

```
Total = PBI_Purch_View[Price] * PBI_Purch_View[Quantity]
```

It might be my understand of how measures work for give my understanding I am changing an existing report from being excel based datasource to direct query and its a pain having to re do these instead of just being able to change connection on the existing report.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not complaining that they don't exist. However, it looks like you are trying to write a measure like you would a calculated column. In a measure, you have to specify the aggregation method since you don't have the row filter context you do in with calculated column.

You probably want a measure that looks something like this:

```
Total = SUMX(PBI_Purch_View, PBI_Purch_View[Price] * PBI_Purch_View[Quantity])
```

If you want the `Total` as a calculated column instead, your formula would work fine.

Comment: strange thing is it was in this format in my so in the orginal power bi document so am i adding the wrong type of column